# Extension Error for Trizetto Facets extension

Tags: com, add-in

[image: Extension Error for Trizetto Facets extension.]

Hi folks,
I don't know if anyone here can help, but we are at wits' end. We use the Facets product from Trizetto, and I inherited an extension that works fine in production. All I changed was one URL in one method and its overload, and now none of us can run it in either Windows 7 or XP SP3. Debugging it or running the installed extension gives the error shown. The extensions guide (like much of what Trizetto has put out) is pretty useless, and they have no support links or knowledge base online. Has anyone encountered this sort of thing, and can you lead me to any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Trizetto is fairly straight forward for extensions.  In this case your custom code is returning an error when Facets attempts to invoke it.  Can you run your code outside of Facets and see what happens?  A test rig helps here.